# addTarget for another class

Tags: ios, uibutton

I have a UIView that has some buttons that I need to add actions to.

I've tried the this:

```
 HeaderViewController * header = [[HeaderViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"HeaderViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

[header.aboutUs addTarget:self action:@selector(aboutUsPage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[header.MyLibrary addTarget:self action:@selector(myLibraryPage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.tableView addParallaxWithView:header.view andHeight:229];
```

But the button is not responding at all.

What have I done wrong.

Comment: ...have you breakpointed the methods you're trying to call? Or done any sort of debugging?

Comment: U have put the target as self, instead of self u have to put reference for that class where u want to implement the action.

Comment: Is it crashing after button click?

Comment: `[self.tableView addParallaxWithView:header.view andHeight:229];` is this some category method? Make sure your buttons are not covered by some other UIView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the thing, You are creating the view controller and then setting targets and actions for buttons that are referenced as the view controller's property.

I suspect that if you log or put a breakpoint just before you set the target and actions and then step through, the buttons will be nil.

View controllers load their views lazily. So although you have created the view controller, you haven't asked it to load it's view. So the buttons have not been created from the nib. So the properties are nil, and not target action is getting set.

The first option to fixing it is to move the last line so it looks like this:

```
[self.tableView addParallaxWithView:header.view andHeight:229];
[header.aboutUs addTarget:self action:@selector(aboutUsPage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[header.MyLibrary addTarget:self action:@selector(myLibraryPage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

That way you are calling the view, which will initialise it, and the button parameters should not be nil after this.

The classier way of doing this sort of thing is to define a protocol for responding to clicks on the button, and make the calling view controller a delegate that implements the protocol methods. That way you only have to set the delegate when you create the object, and you don't have to configure the buttons each time.

Answer (score 0):

If you write :

```
[header.aboutUs setTarget:self];
```

AND if your class (I mean here self) implements the function `aboutUsPage:`, it should work.

Comment: @Abizern: Umm, header.aboutUs is a property of the view controller, which very well could be a button....

Comment: @Abizem Well, if I have two view controller vc1 and vc2, vc1 having a button b1 performing selector s1, and if vc2 implements s1 too, changing target like I do works...

Comment: Okay - cue my red face, I didn't see it that way.